# Intermittent 400 Bad Request Errors in IIS

Tags: iis, 400, bad-request

We recently upgraded our infrastructure to Windows server 2008 R2 (64 bit), and are now getting intermittent 400 errors on post.

I set up failed request tracing, and have caught a couple of them.

Here are the error details:

> ModuleName
>   IsapiModule
>
> Notification
>   128
>
> HttpStatus
>   400
>
> HttpReason
>   Bad Request
>
> HttpSubStatus
>   0
>
> ErrorCode
>   2147943395
>
> Notification
>   EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
>
> ErrorCode
>   The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)

Any ideas?

Comment: Which ISAPI was running on that request?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell that - it just says ModuleName: IsapiModule.  How would i look that up?

Comment: What application framework is the application running? ASP/ASP.Net/other. You're using Failed Request Tracing, so it'll show you the module that's running in ISAPIModule, or at worst you can look at the original request extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer was a bug in our Kemp load balancers.  So far we've had nothing but problems with them.